# WSO2 using xpath to get element inside a xml-content property

Tags: xml, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I have got an local entry in wso2 esb which contains an xml structure. I succeed in loading it into a property, but fail to perform xpath sentences over it for looking for a node value.

How could I do this?

Comment: Problem fixed. I did it using javascript. I load the local entry in a message context property with a property mediator. After that, by an script mediator, load the variable and process the content with Javascript+E4X and set the result again in a new message context property.

In future, I will try to make a sequence template with this functionality

Answer (score 2):

The elements in a XML file(this can be in a local entry , registry or even as a property) can be accessed using property mediator function. Following sample configuration shows how to get the value of the node 'b' in test.xml file in the local config repository.

ie:- test.xml --> `<a>Helloo<b>World</b></a>`

```
<property name="test" expression="get-property('registry','conf:/test.xml')" scope="default" type="OM"/>
<log level="custom">
      <property name="test.b" expression="$ctx:test//b"/>
</log>
```

Comment: where exactly should I situate the test.xml? C:\wso2esb-4.8.1\repository\deployment\server\synapse-configs\default\test.xml ???